# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column, parameter, or variable #9: Cannot find data type json

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

Wanted to create JSON field using Spring boot entity class in SQL Server. Below is the column name

```
@Column(name = "personalDetails", columnDefinition = "json")
@JsonRawValue
String personalDetails;
```

but I am getting the following error.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column, parameter, or variable #9: Cannot find data type json

Comment: JSON isn't a data type in SQL Server; the error is telling you the problem. If you want to store JSON data (in SQL Server), do so in an `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON isn't a data type in SQL Server; the error is telling you the problem. If you want to store JSON data (in SQL Server), do so in an `nvarchar(MAX)`.

[Solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159290/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-column-parameter-or-variable#comment118710187_67159290)